# Django: Error in creating custom fields in Django

Tags: django

I tried this on my model:

```
class NameField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NameField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return str(value).lower()

class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey('State', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]+$',
                                message="Name should only consist of characters")
    name = models.NameField(validators=[name_regex], max_length=100)
    postalcode = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["state", "name"]
```

Now I am getting error as: ***AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'NameField'***
How to resolve this error?

Comment: Instead of `name = models.NameField(validators=[name_regex], max_length=100)` use `name = NameField(validators=[name_regex], max_length=100)` as you are created NameField manually so it won't be available on models. This might solve your error.

Comment: use **`name = NameField(validators=[name_regex], max_length=100)`** instead of `name = models.NameField(validators=[name_regex], max_length=100)`